# Append/Concat multiple ushort values

Tags: c#, number-formatting, concatenation, ushort

I am working on C# application (.Net 4.0). At some situation I want to append the multiple ushort values as mentioned below

```
Ushort a = 123;
Ushort b = 045;
Ushort c = 607;
Ushort d = 008;
```

And I want the result as 12304560700.

Currently with below approach

```
var temp = Convert.ToString(a) + Convert.ToString(b) + Convert.ToString(c) + Convert.ToString(d);
```

I am getting the temp value as 123456078.

I do understand that because of ushort datatype it eliminate all the leading zero. But I am expecting the result as 12304560700.

I may have made the use of padleft method but the length and leading zero counts are not fix, so that option also doesn’t suits my requirement.

I would like to know how I can achieve the same, any small inputs on the same is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the ushorts from? User input?

Comment: not exactly user inputs but from some hardware device which is connected in lan network.

Comment: Can you show how exactly do you get the values? Because `ushort`s can't store things with leading 0s. You have to use another data type. What kind of hardware device? What do the numbers represent?

Comment: $"{a}{b.ToString("d3")}{c}{d.ToString("d3")}".Dump();

Answer (score 0):

You want all your numbers to be formatted using 3 digits, with leading zeros if needed. Looking at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) you get this:

```
var temp = a.ToString("D3") + b.ToString("D3") + ...
```

Comment: please note that length and leading zero counts are not fix, so this wont work

Comment: So does the length need to be equal to the length of the biggest number?

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 123;
int b = 045;
int c = 607;
int d = 008;
```

why cant u do it this way? wont the result be what u want?

```
int temp = a.ToString() + b.ToString() + c.ToString() + d.Substring(d.Length - 2);
```

result as 12304560700.

Comment: Of course not. 045 is the same as 45 and it doesn't need three digits to be printed, just two. Thus: b.ToString() --> "45" not "045".

Answer (score 0):

`ushorts` are not capable of storing numbers with leading zeros. In its eyes, `45` and `045` are the same exact number.

I recommend you to just store the numbers as strings, like this:

```
var a = "123";
var b = "045";
var c = "607";
var d = "008";
```

This is especially easy to do if you are getting these things from the console.

Comment: maybe something like this , if you know there are 3 numbers ,  $"{a.ToString("d3")}{b.ToString("d3")}{c.ToString("d3")}{d.ToString("d3")}".Dump();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning values to ushort assign it to string or var.

eg: string a="123"; string b="011" etc or var a="123" etc

then var temp = a+b+... this will work. No Ushort value store data leading with Zero.
Thank you